# CoreBluetooth - UUID not set for a service

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, uuid, core-bluetooth

I'm  trying to use Bluetooth between a mac and an Iphone. But the UUID seems not to be set on the mac. I use on the mac :

```
 self.characteristic = [[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"DDCA9B49-A6F5-462F-A89A-C2144083CA7F"] properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify value:nil permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable];

    self.service = [[CBMutableService alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"BA6878AE-4F70-41AD-B793-8F8AF2A2811E"] primary:YES];
    self.service.characteristics = @[self.characteristic];

    NSLog(@"UUID SERVICE : %@",self.service.UUID.description);//WTF ?
    [self.peripheralManager addService:self.service];
```

But the NSlog print

```
UUID SERVICE : Unknown (<ba6878ae 4f7041ad b7938f8a f2a2811e>)
```

And I think that's why the Iphone doesn't find the mac while trying scanForPeripheralsWithService (On the Iphone)

```
 self.serviceAlert = @"BA6878AE-4F70-41AD-B793-8F8AF2A2811E";

//add the services to the Array
self.services = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [CBUUID UUIDWithString:self.serviceAlert],
                 nil];

self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];

[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:self.services options:nil];
```

Any idea why the service's UUID isn't set properly on the mac ?

Edit : I use

`[peripheral startAdvertising:@{
                                   CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: @"hello"
                                   }];`

In the didAddServicemethod; I can find the service whith `[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil]`

Comment: It appears to be set properly. It's showing you the value you initialized it with.

Comment: Are your sure ? When I try the same NSlog on the Iphone, I get something without the "unknown" word : `UUID SERVICE : BA6878AE-4F70-41AD-B793-8F8AF2A2811E`

Comment: CoreBluetooth on MacOS is implemented differently than on iOS, and in particular CBUUID's description method is different. Look at what it printed out: "ba6878ae 4f7041ad b7938f8a f2a2811e". That's your UUID string you initialized it with.

Comment: When do you advertise your service? Plus, if you try to `[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];` Do you find it?

Comment: If I use `[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];`, I find it.
I advertise the service in the `- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral didAddService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error` method

Comment: Thank you quellish ; So I need to find why the service isn't discovered properly by the Iphone then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the solution, I am just very stupid. The service advertisement wasn't the good one

`[peripheral startAdvertising:@{
                                   CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey :
                                       @[self.service.UUID]                }];`

Is the good way to do it.